# Regular Expression Java Pattern

Tags: java, regex, string, char, pattern-matching

I should match two numbers bigger than 0 separated from a whitespace

`^\d+?\s\d+?$`

I tried that but it clearly doesn't work
then I should also match a string that begins with # and ends with # and inside there should be a fixed amount of char, that can be any char, determined by a variable w - 2.

`String regex = "#.{" + (w - 2) + "}$";`

`return Pattern.matches(regex, stringToMatch );`

tried that but doesnt work.

Comment: When you say "doesn't work" what doesn't work about it? What is your input and what is your expected output?

Comment: `"#.{" + (w - 2) + "}$";` should be `"#.{" + (w - 2) + "}#";`...

Comment: the first doesn't even compile, it gives me invalid escape sequence and the second one if `w = 4` it doens't recognize `#gf#`

Comment: `^\d+?\s\d+?$` should maybe be `\\d+?\\s\\d+`?...

Comment: Did you make the changes I suggested?

Comment: yes it worked for the second one

Comment: What about the first?

Comment: no the second one didn't work, it says illegal repetition near index 1

Comment: Try this: `\\d+\\s\\d+`

Comment: To match a number greater than 0 you can't just use `\d+` as this would match `0`.
Either use `\d*[1-9]` if there are leading zeros or `[1-9]+` otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way (I know ;) to match a non-zero number, while asserting it's a valid number and allowing for leading zeroes, is

```
\d*[1-9]\d*
```

This makes sure all tested characters are digits and at least one of them isn't a zero.

So your first declaration should be something like

```
String regex = "^\\d*[1-9]\\d*\\s\\d*[1-9]\\d*$";
```

(You could do similar things with look-around, but they're less effective - especially for longer numbers.)

---

As for the second part of your question, as mentioned in comments, you've forgotten the ending `#`. If it's allowed to be preceded and followed by other text:

```
String regex = "#.{" + (w - 2) + "}#";
```

If it should be the only text:

```
String regex = "^#.{" + (w - 2) + "}#$";
```

Hope this helps.

Regards